# Filter IP-List with Batch-Program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a list full of servers and I want to check which ones are running and which are offline. So I want to ping them once to see if they respond. I filter them with "findstr TTL". But now I want to save only the IP into the "result.txt"-file not the whole string, but I don't know how I can do that. I searched on the internet and I think I have to do another For-Loop, but I don't have the syntax right. So I just want to write a Batch-Program that reads the servers (ip list) from a file and puts the running pings into a new result file. Thank you for your Help.

```
set amount_of_pings=1
set file_name=server.txt
set result_file_name=result_server.txt

FOR /F "delims=:" %%i in (%file_name%) do (
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (ping -n %amount_of_pings% %%i^| findstr "TTL") do (

   )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test for the result of the `find` command, and if it does not raise errorlevel, the ip is alive and echoed to report file.

If a TTL timeout in ping is considered as a running machine, then your test is correct. If not, better include the equal sign in the test for TTL value.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "amount_of_pings=1"
    set "file_name=server.txt"
    set "result_file_name=result_server.txt"

    break > "%result_file_name%"
    for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in ("%file_name%") do (
        echo testing %%i
        ping -n %amount_of_pings% %%i | find "TTL=" >nul 2>nul && echo %%i >> "%result_file_name%"
    )
```